# How to make condition for "hibernate" check to database

Tags: java, hibernate

I made a program that it will save the data if there aren't same value at field of database
and it will update the data if there are same value at field of database,

I got stuck to make "hibernate" can check the value in database

any help will be pleasure
thanks in advance

now i can give condition for hibernate to check if the data is exist or not... when the condition is true this code work but when the condition is false i got some error...

update my code

```
            Query query = session.createQuery("from CoreService where MODULE_NAME= :lolo1 and OBJECT_NAME= :lolo2 and SYSTEM_ID= :lolo3 and LOG_DATE= :lolo4");
            query.setParameter("lolo1", module);
            query.setParameter("lolo2", object);
            query.setParameter("lolo3", system_id);
            query.setParameter("lolo4", log_date);

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<CoreService> result = query.list();
            if(result.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("LOLOH");

                CoreService data = new CoreService();
                data.setMODULE_NAME(module);
                data.setCATEGORY("SYSTEMID");
                data.setSYSTEM_ID(system_id);
                data.setCOUNTER_SYSTEM(1);
                data.setOBJECT_NAME(object);
                data.setCOUNTER_SERVICE(1);
                data.setLOG_DATE(log_date);
                data.setUPDATE_LOG(update_log);

                session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(data);
                session.getTransaction().commit();

            }else{
                System.out.println("LELEH");

                CoreService data = new CoreService();

                data.setCATEGORY("SYSTEMID");

                data.setCOUNTER_SYSTEM(2);

                data.setCOUNTER_SERVICE(2);



                session.beginTransaction();
                session.update(data);
                session.getTransaction().commit();

            }
```

here there are the error ~

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: The given object has a null identifier: id.co.bni.coreservice.model.CoreService
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.getUpdateId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:272)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultUpdateEventListener.getUpdateId(DefaultUpdateEventListener.java:72)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:240)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultUpdateEventListener.java:57)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireUpdate(SessionImpl.java:742)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:730)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:722)
at id.co.bni.coreservice.controller.CoreServiceController.LoadData(CoreServiceController.java:271)
at id.co.bni.coreservice.controller.CoreServiceController.actionPerformed(CoreServiceController.java:167)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this is my class Model ~ (note: my ID is auto increment)

```
package id.co.bni.coreservice.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;


@Entity
@Table(name = "coreservice")
public class CoreService {

private Integer ID;
private String MODULE_NAME;
private String CATEGORY;
private String SYSTEM_ID;
private Integer COUNTER_SYSTEM;
private String OBJECT_NAME;
private Integer COUNTER_SERVICE;
private Date LOG_DATE;
private Date UPDATE_LOG;

/**
 * @return
 */

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
public Integer getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(Integer ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

@Column(name = "MODULE_NAME")
public String getMODULE_NAME() {
    return MODULE_NAME;
}

public void setMODULE_NAME(String MODULE_NAME) {
    this.MODULE_NAME = MODULE_NAME;
}

@Column(name = "CATEGORY")
public String getCATEGORY() {
    return CATEGORY;
}

public void setCATEGORY(String CATEGORY) {
    this.CATEGORY = CATEGORY;
}

@Column(name = "SYSTEM_ID")
public String getSYSTEM_ID() {
    return SYSTEM_ID;
}

public void setSYSTEM_ID(String SYSTEM_ID) {
    this.SYSTEM_ID = SYSTEM_ID;
}

@Column(name = "COUNTER_SYSTEM")
public Integer getCOUNTER_SYSTEM() {
    return COUNTER_SYSTEM;
}

public void setCOUNTER_SYSTEM(Integer COUNTER_SYSTEM) {
    this.COUNTER_SYSTEM = COUNTER_SYSTEM;
}

@Column(name = "OBJECT_NAME")
public String getOBJECT_NAME() {
    return OBJECT_NAME;
}

public void setOBJECT_NAME(String OBJECT_NAME) {
    this.OBJECT_NAME = OBJECT_NAME;
}

@Column(name = "COUNTER_SERVICE")
public Integer getCOUNTER_SERVICE() {
    return COUNTER_SERVICE;
}

public void setCOUNTER_SERVICE(Integer COUNTER_SERVICE) {
    this.COUNTER_SERVICE = COUNTER_SERVICE;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "LOG_DATE")
public Date getLOG_DATE() {
    return LOG_DATE;
}

public void setLOG_DATE(Date LOG_DATE) {
    this.LOG_DATE = LOG_DATE;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "UPDATE_LOG")
public Date getUPDATE_LOG() {
    return UPDATE_LOG;
}

public void setUPDATE_LOG(Date UPDATE_LOG) {
    this.UPDATE_LOG = UPDATE_LOG;
}


/**
 * @param args
 */
}
```

Comment: please post your code here !!

Comment: How did you try to do it and what's the problem ?

Comment: @mohsinazeem sorry dude, i forgot to post my code... @Frederic i've been try to make `List<>` but i can't make the hibernate to check the database for same value

Comment: You should post the **minimal** code to reproduce the issue, & not the bunch of code that you're working on & not related to the issue.

Comment: @RAS I'm sorry, my bad :)

Comment: I think you should use `session.saveOrUpdate(data)`. It inserts `data`, if `data` is a new object(PK not given) & updates the `data` (if PK is found).

Comment: @erencan i'm using mysql for this application ~

Comment: @RAS i've update my code, now i can give condition for hibernate to check if the data is exist or not... when the condition is true this code work but when the condition is false i got some error... any idea??

Comment: your id generation strategy is not right as exception said `The given object has a null identifier`. can you post your entity class and db defination?

Comment: @splatter_fadli, the code is not working for else part?

Comment: @RAS yupss, when the code meet "false" condition i got that error, but @Sudhir give me this code `CoreService data = (CoreService )result.get(0);` and everything work well... i just wanna thank to you RAS for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Else block you have to get the data from result & then set the required values.

```
else{
                System.out.println("LELEH");

                CoreService data = (CoreService )result.get(0);

                data.setCATEGORY("SYSTEMID");

                data.setCOUNTER_SYSTEM(2);

                data.setCOUNTER_SERVICE(2);



                session.beginTransaction();
                session.update(data);
                session.getTransaction().commit();

            }
```